# Algorithm(s) for computing an elementary symmetric polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, algorithms, symmetric-polynomials

I've run into an application where I need to compute a bunch of [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). It is trivial to compute a sum or product of quantities, of course, so my concern is with computing the "other" symmetric polynomials.

For instance (I use here the notation $\sigma_n^k$ for the $k$-th symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables), the Vieta formulae allow me to compute a bunch of symmetric polynomials all at once like so:

$$\begin{align*}
&(x+t)(x+u)(x+v)(x+w)\\
&\qquad =x^4+\sigma_4^1(t,u,v,w)x^3+\sigma_4^2(t,u,v,w)x^2+\sigma_4^3(t,u,v,w)x+\sigma_4^4(t,u,v,w)
\end{align*}$$

and, as I have said, $\sigma_4^1$ and $\sigma_4^4$ are trivial to compute on their own without having to resort to Vieta.

But what if I want to compute $\sigma_4^3$ only without having to compute all the other symmetric polynomials? More generally, my application involves a large-ish number of arguments, and I want to be able to compute "isolated" symmetric polynomials without having to compute all of them.

Thus, I'm looking for an algorithm for computing $\sigma_n^k$ given only $k$ and the arguments themselves, without computing the other symmetric polynomials. Are there any, or can I not do better than Vieta?

Comment: How would you use Vita to calculate the polynomials? Vita mixes them all up..

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23683/755.

Answer (score 10):

There's a dynamic programming algorithm that is $O(nk)$ using a recurrence relation. If we define $S_n^k = \sigma_n^k(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, then we have $$S_n^k = S_{n-1}^k + x_n S_{n-1}^{k-1}$$ which allows one to compute $S_n^k$ by filling an $n \times k$ matrix, where (almost) every cell takes constant time to fill.

(The base case is of course $S_n^0 = 1$ for all $n$ and $S_n^k = 0$ for all $n$ and $k \neq 0$.)

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your base case statement "... and $S_n^k=0$ for all $n$ and $k\ne0$". Maybe I don't understand the wording, but to me it reads like saying $S_n^k=0$ identically (except when $k=0$).

Comment: Maybe you meant $S_n^k=0$ for $k > n$.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Newton-Girard formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums).
The elementary symmetric polynomial have [representation as determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressions_as_determinants):
$$
p_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^k = x_1^k+\cdots+x_n^k \\
e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}
$$
$$    e_k=\frac1{k!} \begin{vmatrix}p_1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\ p_2 & p_1 & 2 & 0 & \cdots \\ \vdots&& \ddots & \ddots \\ p_{k-1} & p_{k-2} & \cdots & p_1 & k-1 \\ p_k & p_{k-1} & \cdots & p_2 & p_1 \end{vmatrix} 
$$
We can compute this determinant using $O(k^2)$ additions and multiplications, using the following general result (from citation at end):

> Let $A_n$ be an $n\times n$ lower Hessenberg matrix, meaning that $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $j\ge i+2$. For each $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $A_k$ be the $k\times k$ submatrix consisting of the upper $k$ rows and leftmost $k$ columns of $A_n$. Then for all $n\ge 1$,
>
> $$\det A_n=a_{n,n}\det A_{n-1}+\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-r}a_{n,r}\prod_{j=r}^{n-1}a_{j,j+1}\det A_{r-1}$$
> with the convention that $\det A_0=1$.

Since it takes $O(nk)$ to compute the list $p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n),\dots,p_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the total complexity of this method is $O(nk+k^2)=O(nk)$ additions and multiplications.

> Nathan D. Cahill, John R. D'Errico, Darren A. Narayan & Jack Y. Narayan (2002) *Fibonacci Determinants*, The College Mathematics Journal, 33:3, 221-225, DOI: 10.1080/07468342.2002.11921945

Comment: Do you also have a fast way of computing those determinants? The raw method takes `O(n^2.4)` operations. I suppose the near symmetry might help? or maybe not? Perhaps it can play into some sampling/approximation algorithm...

Comment: @Thomas, a lower Hessenberg matrix like the one in this answer can be decomposed in $O(n^2)$ operations; the determinant is then easily obtained from the triangular factor. Have a look at "Hyman's method", for instance.

Comment: Is there a numerically more stable computation method? For small and positive $x$'s, I would like to get compute the logarithm of $e_k$ instead of $e_k$.

Answer (score 8):

You can compute $\sigma^k_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in $O(n \log^2 k)$ time, using FFT-based polynomial multiplication.  The details are explained here and are apparently due to Ben-Or: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33506/5038.

Quote from that post, with notation changed to match this question.

> Here's how.  Introduce a formal unknown $y$, and consider the polynomial
> $$P(y) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i y).$$
> Note that since the $x_i$'s are known constants, this is a univariate polynomial with unknown $y$ and with degree $n$.  Now you can note that the coefficient of $y^k$ in $P(y)$ is exactly $\sigma_n^k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so to evaluate all the $\sigma_n^0,\dots,\sigma_n^n$, it suffices to compute $P(y)$.
>
> This makes it possible to compute $P(y)$ in $O(n \lg^2 n)$ time: build a balanced binary tree of polynomials with the $(1+x_i y)$'s at the leaves, and multiply the polynomials.  Multiplying two polynomials of degree $d$ takes $O(d \lg d)$ time using FFT techniques, so we get the recurrence $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n \lg n)$, which solves to $T(n) = O(n \lg^2 n)$.  For convenience, I am ignoring $\text{poly}(\lg \lg n)$ factors.
>
> If you care about the case where $k$ is very small, you can compute $\sigma_n^0,\dots,\sigma_n^k$ in $O(n \lg^2 k)$ time using similar tricks, keeping in mind that you only care about $P(x) \bmod y^{k+1}$ (i.e., throwing away all terms of $y^{k+1}$ or higher powers of $y$).

This is asymptotically faster than any of the other methods proposed in any of the other answers.

Moreover, you can compute all of the values $\sigma^1_n(x_1,\dots,x_n), \sigma^2_n(x_1,\dots,x_n), \dots, \sigma^n_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in just $O(n \log^2 k)$ time, using the same methods.

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134212)

Answer (score 4):

Let us use the symbols $u_1, u_2, ....$, for the indeterminates $t, u, v, ...$ in the question.
The computation will be given in terms of a new set of indeterminates, $x_1, x_2, ....$, whose connection to the original indeterminates is given by:

$x_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i^j$

We define the derivation operator $\Delta$ acting on the new set of indeterminates as follows:

$\Delta x_j = j x_{j+1}$

$\Delta ab = a \Delta b + b \Delta a$

Then the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial is given by:

$\sigma_n^i = \frac{1}{i!}(x_1-\Delta)^{i-1}x_1$

The evaluation is performed in terms of the new indeterminates, after the evaluation, the expressions of the new determinates in terms of the original indeterminates need to be substituted.

Comment: Apllying $i=2$ gives $\frac12 (x_1x_1 - \Delta x_1)=\frac12 (x_1x_1 - 2 x_2)$, or did I miss something...?

Comment: How fast is this then? After expanding the $(x_1-\triangle)^{i-1}$ don't you still have to do $O(n^2)$ work?

Answer (score 2):

A simple divide-and-conquer recursion looks like it comes in at $O(nk)$, just like the recurrence given by @BenKuhn.  Split the variables into two halves, and inductively compute $\sigma_{n/2}^j$ for $j=0,\ldots,k$ evaluated on both halves.  Iterate $r$ times, where $n\approx 2^r k$; the total work required is $2^r$ evaluations of $\{\sigma_k^j\mid 0\le j\le k\}$.  But each of these sets can be done in $O(k^2)$ work using Vieta, so the total work is $O(2^r k^2)=O(nk)$.

It's probably worth remarking that you can evaluate $\sigma_n^{n-k}$ by evaluating $\sigma_n^k$ on the reciprocals of the variables.  So you're in good shape if $k$ is either very small, or nearly $n$.