# Using elementary polynomials to solve system of linear polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

**Problem Statement**

I am given a finite set of monic polynomials in t, parameterized by $r_i$

$X_i = t - r_i$

where the $r_i$ are guaranteed unique. Neither $t$ nor $r_i$ are known, only $X_i$. I would like to solve for t **or** every $r_i$.

---

**Attempt at solution using elementary polynomials.**

I am trying to use elementary symmetric polynomials to solve for $t$. I know that

$g_n(t+r_i) = \prod_j^n X_j = \sum_j^{n} (-1)^j \sigma_{j,n} (t^{n-j})$

where $\sigma_{j,n}$ is the j-th elementary symmetric polynomial on n variables (usually this is written just $\sigma_{j}$).

Because I don't have access to the roots themselves, I am trying something like:

$\Delta_n = g_{n+1} - g_{n} =  (t - r_{n+1} -1)\prod_{i}^{n}(X_i) =  \sum_j^{n+1} (-1)^j \sigma_{j,n+1} (t^{n-j+1}) -  \sum_j^{n} (-1)^j \sigma_{j,n} (t^{n-j})\\
= [(-1)^{n+1}\sigma_j^{n+1}] + t^n \sum_j (-1)^j t^{-j} [t \sigma_{j,n+1} - \sigma_{j,n}] $

I would like to somehow relate $\sigma_{j,n+1}$ to $\sigma_{j,n}$, with the intention of simplifying the bracketed last term and solving for $t^n$ using the known product $(t - r_{n+1} -1)\prod_{i}^{n}(X_i)$. Is such a thing possible? Barring that, are there other methods to solve the system? The [closest thing I can find on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/algorithms-for-computing-an-elementary-symmetric-polynomial) relates $\sigma_{j+1,n}$ to $\sigma_{j,n}$. I have also looked [at methods for approximating the roots using derivatives](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19720015971.pdf) and [exact solutions given knowledge of the roots](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/20sympoly.pdf) (pp5)

Answer (score 0):

$t=0$, $r_i=-X_i$ is a solution. For any constant $c$, $t=c$, $r_i=c-X_i$ is a solution.

Adding higher order complications will not change anything in this picture. Is there some information missing?

Comment: The information missing is that I am working in a system in which I know $X_i = t - r_i$, but neither t not $r_i$ are individually known, controllable, or separable. I only have $X_i$. If it were otherwise, you would be absolutely correct.

Comment: You already said that. Your system of equations is still underdetermined, $n$ equations for $n+1$ unknowns. This gives a solution set of dimension 1, in this case a straight line as parametrized in the answer.