# Generalized binomial theorem

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

I want to find the coefficients of the $n$-th degree polynomial obtained from the expansion of the binomial product:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n{(x-a_i)}$$

where $x$ and $a_i$ are real numbers. Is there any efficient formula or recursive algorithm to calculate such coefficients? I found in wikipedia the formula for the more general case of the multi-binomial product but it does not seem very efficient.

Comment: These are called Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case covered by [Vieta's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n (x-a_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k x^k, $$
where $ A_n = 1 $, and the others are given by
\begin{align}
A_{n-1} &= -\sum_i a_i, \\
A_{n-2} &= + \sum_{i_1 < i_2} a_{i_1} a_{i_2}, \\
&\,\,\vdots \\
A_0 &= (-1)^n a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n,
\end{align}
where $A_k$ contains all possible products of $n-k$ distinct $a_i$s. This is the simplest possible way of writing these in general.

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, what if not all $a_i$s are different? My other concern would be the efficiency of these formulas for large $n$.

Comment: There isn't a major simplification if the $a_i$ are not distinct. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30807/221811) has some suggestions for efficient ways of computing the symmetric polynomials involved, but this is the extent of my knowledge on the matter.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use the formulas, but I'm lost with the indices of the $A_{n-3}$ coefficient. I'm guessing they will be $i_1<i_2<i_3$, is it correct?. Also  if I expand $\prod_{i=1}^n{(x+a_i)}$ instead of $\prod_{i=1}^n{(x-a_i)}$ would it mean that all coefficients $A_k$ will have a plus sign in front of the summation?

Comment: Yes, correct on both.