# Factoring the sum of polynomial coefficient "division"

Tags: polynomials, convolution, symmetric-polynomials

Define the coefficient $B = (b_0, \cdots b_n)$ of elementarty polynomial product of $A=(a_0 \cdots, a_n)$.  $B = \sum_{i=0}^N b_ix^i  = \prod_{i=0}^N(1+a_ix) $.
Use $f(A) = B$ to get it's coefficient.

Given a length $n$ sequence $A$, i need to compute $g(A) := \frac{1}{n+1}\langle f(A), 1/f(1_n)\rangle$. Here $1_n$ denote length $n$, 1 sequence. $1/f(1_n)$ is the element-wise reciprocal. and $\langle, \rangle$ is the inner product.

My question is: is it possible to factor $g(A)$? E.g. compute some quantity using the first half of $A$ and the second half of $A$ independently and then join them together.

The reason why I want to do this is when $n$ is big, I can easily run into a precision problem. My code would overflow :(.

Comment: The constant coefficient of $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i x)$ is $1$, but there is no requirement that $b_0 = 1$.  So almost always, $f$ doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, I missed the leading $0$ term, $f$ is not some fancy function, but simply multiply a bunch of low degree polynomials @EricTowers

Comment: Does not correct the omission.  Try it with $B = (2)$.  There is no $A$ that gives this $B$.

Answer (score 1):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

- The coefficients $b_i$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Definition)
  $\,b_i=e_i\left(a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n\right)\,$, which can be calculated more efficiently than direct brute force, see for example the answers and links under [Algorithm(s) for computing an elementary symmetric polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/algorithms-for-computing-an-elementary-symmetric-polynomial).
- Let $\displaystyle\,f(1_n) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i = (1+x)^n\,$ then $\displaystyle\,c_i = \binom{n}{i} = \frac{(n)_i}{i!}\,$ where $\,(n)_i\,$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), which can be calculated iteratively as $\displaystyle\,c_{i+1}=\frac{n-i}{i+1}\,c_i\,$.

Then $\displaystyle\,(n+1)\,g(A) = \langle f(A), 1/f(1_n)\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{b_i}{c_i}\,$ where $\,b_i, \,c_i\,$ can be calculated as above.

Comment: Thank you for the links, just want to highlight the aspect I was looking for is about overflow issues, as I might have $N=50$ and $a_n ~ 1e5$, such that the polynomial coefficient can be too big

Comment: @pengyu Calculating $b_i,c_i$ recursively lessens the chance of "avoidable" overflows in general, because (in a sense) it takes the most direct path of evaluation. But if the end result does not fit into the types you are using, then you have an "unavoidable" overflow on your hands, which you are going to hit no matter how clever the intermediate calculations.

Comment: Yes and no.. as $b_i, c_i$ cancels each other, and the aggregated result is known stable,  if I can figure out a way to aggregate in low degree and recombine, it would have less chance to overflow

Comment: @pengyu You could probably "merge" the recursions for $b_i, c_i$ into a combined recursion for the ratio $b_i / c_i$. As to whether anything "*cancels each other*", that depends on particulars of the problem, which you did not post. If you have additional knowledge about the $\,a_i\,$ then you should edit that into the question, since it could help better "tune" the answers.